# AbiWord not using GTK2 theme

Tags: linux, themes, gtk, openbox, abiword

I have a linux desktop that uses Openbox and GTK2. I installed abiword, because honestly, I don't use Libreoffice Impress, etc. at all. I just use a word processor. Anyway, I installed Abiword and opened it, and I noticed that Abiword wasn't using my selected gtk2 theme.

Here's a picture of Abiword:

[image: http://imgur.com/cLvwVuC]

And here's a picture of a correctly working application:

[image: http://imgur.com/xgWLtdD]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not use your GTK2 theme because it is built with GTK3. The picture is exactly what the default "Raleigh" theme looks like in GTK3.

If your theme supports both gtk-2.0 and gtk-3.0, you can edit `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` to set it for GTK3 programs as well; but it is very likely that you'll have to use a different theme.

```
[Settings]
gtk-theme-name=Adwaita
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly! Though, on a side note, I noticed that the page is just stuck on the left. Any way to make it sort of float to the center? It's not really a big deal, I'm just wondering.